# How to returned the value from DB of non-updatable fields when persisting an entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can get Hibernate to return the actual property value of persisted objects when saving an entity?

```
Entity {
   @Column(name = "name", updatable = false)
   private String someProperty;

   ...
}
```

When saving the one Entity object, the return object I want to have the persisted value of the "ignored" fields and not the value of the saved object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EntityManager.refresh()`:

```
entityManager.merge(entity);   // update entity
entityManager.flush();         // invoke SQL to insert updated data
entityManager.refresh(entity); // reload ignored fields
```

It should update fields which are marked with `updatable = false` to persisted values